# Difference between Gestell and Rahmen?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, meaning-in-context, german-to-english, heidegger

I am reading Heidegger, and he uses Gestell, which is frame, but he uses it as a verb, "enframing" (which translates to Umrahmung). This is rooted in "Rahmen".

Which is the best word for the phrase "enframing is danger" ?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add some context, in particular the sentence that you read?

Comment: A *Gestell* is a three-dimensional frame. Something that isn't flat. Hence the name, you can *hinstellen* == *put it standing* somewhere.

Comment: "Umrahmung" is not a verb, but a noun, which suggests that "enframing" (in that context) may as well be a noun. The corresponding verb would be "umrahmen".

Comment: With that said, and after skimming through a few texts to see what "enframing" is about in the context of said author, let me say that to me as a native speaker, using "Gestell" sounds really weird. Besides the physical object, "Rahmen" and derived words are commonly used in a figurative sense, but a "Gestell" is rarely, if ever, anything but a physical object, something like a stand or a support.

Comment: If Heidegger invents a new term and that term is translated to English, you cannot just translate that back to German and expect it to make sense.
Are you reading Heidegger in German or in English? I really do not understand your question.

Comment: This is a philosophical *terminus technicus* that wants to emphasise the *passive* nature of necessarily always being in a frame of or (en)framed in social, linguistical, and cultural structures. Like one speaks of a thug persued by the police and having nowhere left to go as "Er wurde *gestellt*", i.e. in a determinate, unvoluntary position ("Stellung") relative to the world. Therefore relevant: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/29520/what-exactly-is-gestell-in-heidegger

Answer (score 4):

Heidegger is known to be extremely creative with the usage of terminology, he commonly takes standard terms and puts them in a specific contextual meaning in his works, but with a strong tendency to neglect the definition. Sometimes, you are actually better off to just call the term 'x' instead of looking for any meaning in the word itself outside of Heidegger's works.  There is a saying that goes like:

> Heidegger hatte die ärgerliche Gewohnheit, deutsch zu sprechen

(Leaving the annoying task of being expected to understand what he meant to the poor German-speaking world)

I am not sure if it makes a lot of sense to translate such terms in Heidegger's works - And if yes, you should use standard translations - Typically, *Gestell* in Heidegger's works is translated to *enframing* (the substantive). So no, he doesn't *use it as a verb*. *Gestell* does not have a closely associated verb in German (so it is a bit misleading that translators seem to have agreed upon a substantiation of a verb in the English translations).

So your translation should simply be

> Das Gestell ist eine Gefahr

(Which doesn't make a lot of sense without context to me)

Comment: +1 for everything on Heidegger. Just want to mention that there is actually a verb _(sich) gestellen_, which is probably mostly used in its substantivation _Gestellung_. See https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gestellung This is very probably not relevant in this context - because it does not relate to _Gestell_, which is derived from the verb _stellen_, but just in case, the Heidegger text in question is not  referring to _Gestell_, but to _gestellen_, this could be a lead to follow if you are searching for the reason why Heidegger used that particular word.